# IE9 unresponsive after updates

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-9

After allowing the last few updates to self-install, I have found that when clicking on the IE icon, it pauses, then does nothing. the start menu will populate, with some access to some internal programs, but IE and other programs will not launch. This is a new factory-installed box, with no other browsers installed. AVG Free, Office 2003, skype and CC Cleaner are the only non-OEM programs. computer worked fine until this past week, I have had to use system restore to roll back to last week to have any functionality.

Updates applied using Windows Updates

[KB2604115](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-035) Net Framework 3.5

[KB2656411](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-034)

[KB2604121](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-035) Net Framework 4.0

[KB2467173](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2467173)

[KB2658846](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-034)

[KB2659262](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-034)

[KB2660649](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-034)

[KB2676562](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-034)

[KB2688338](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-032)

[KB2690533](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-033)

[KB2505438](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2505438)

[KB2695962](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/advisory/2695962)

Comment: What is your method of updating IE9? manual install or windows update?

Comment: the automatic windows updates. Microsoft Office File Validation Add-in

Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2604115) (KB2656411) (KB2604121)

Security Update for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (KB2467173)

Security Update for Windows 7 for x64 (KB2658846) (KB2659262) (KB2660649) (KB2676562) (KB2688338)(KB2690533)(KB2505438)

Update Rollup for ActiveX Killbits(KB2695962)
 these are the updates, I have not isolated the offending one yet.

Comment: First thing to try is an IE reset...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings-in-Internet-Explorer-9

Comment: Perhaps try IE10 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/download-ie

Answer (score 1):

Dean, I had the same problem, and it was KB2658846 that caused IE9 to become unresponsive. I uninstalled the update, and IE9 worked normally again. I've hidden the update so I'm not prompted to reinstall it. I've reported it to Microsoft, but no resolution so far.